# UK Tier 4 Visa - Not listing all visited countries in the application by mistake

Tags: visas, uk

I was so careless that I forgot to fill in a country (Singapore) that I had visited during the past ten years in the UK Tier 4 Visa application. However, I've already paid and submitted the application. Is there anyway to amend the form? If not, will my mistake make a substantial impact to my application?